Canonical commutation relation in QFT
The canonical commutation relation in QFT with say one (non-free) scalar real field $\phi$ is
$$[\phi(\vec x,t),\dot \phi(\vec y,t)]=i\hbar\delta^{(3)}(\vec x-\vec y).$$
Is this equation satisfied by the bare field or the renormalized one?

The renormalized field.

@Prahar: Why this is the case?
